# maxima code : convert decimal to binary and vice versa

Tags: binary, decimal, block, maxima

i have to create a maxima code that will automatically convert decimal (like 40.75) to binary number and vice versa .. but i'm having trouble on converting the .75 part.

Here's the code that i was able to make.

```
bin_integ(n) := simplode(values(n, 2));
values([arg]) := block
(   

    [n: first(arg), b: if length(arg) > 1 then second(arg) else 10, v: [ ], q],   


    do (      


       [n, q]: divide(n, b),     

       v: cons(q, v),   

       if n=0 then return(v)
   )
);

bin_integ(40);
```

this code only works for whole numbers. when i tried inputting the 40.75, it says syntax error.
i already searched for other algorithms that makes the conversion in other programming languages (e.g. c++and java), and  tried to replicate it in Maxima. However, it still doesn't work

[click to view the screencapture of my work in maxima](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7o6m.png)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what's a correct result here, but I will guess that you mean you want something like `bbbb.bbbbb` where `b` is 0 or 1. If so, remember that the `.bbbbb` part with `m` bits just means the integer `bbbbb` divided by `2^m`. So, given a decimal fraction `.ddddd`, try to write that as an integer divided by a power of 2, then find the binary representation of that integer. That works out exactly only if the denominator of the decimal part is a power of 2; otherwise you'll a repeating bit pattern.

Comment: @RobertDodier i don't have an idea how to code that sir.

Comment: One approximation is to find the m bit truncation of a given fraction. Let x be some fraction less than 1. Just multiply x by `2^m` and take the integer part of that, i.e. `floor(x*2^m)`. Then just output the bits for that integer, using the same function which you use for the integer part of the original number.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Mathematics/Numbers#convert_a_number_with_a_repeating_fractional_part

Comment: there are repeating, non-repeting and mixed decimal parts.